# How to calculate consecutiveness in Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data set where I need to calculate Consecutiveness of data if it is meeting certain status. The example dataset is as below. The use case is that, if the exchange id is consecutively having Risky and Unstable status then increment the count by 1 for that week and merge with the dataset. I am trying this using Spark.

```
Date    Exchange Id Status  Consecutiveness
5/05/2017   a   RISKY   0
5/05/2017   b   Stable  0
5/05/2017   c   Stable  0
5/05/2017   d   UNSTABLE    0
5/05/2017   e   UNKNOWN 0
5/05/2017   f   UNKNOWN 0
6/05/2017   a   RISKY   1
6/05/2017   b   Stable  0
6/05/2017   c   Stable  0
6/05/2017   d   UNSTABLE    1
6/05/2017   e   UNSTABLE    1
6/05/2017   f   UNKNOWN 0
```

My approach was as follows.

1. Create dataframe for current date exchange having risky and unstable
   condition
2. Create another dataframe for the previous date for exchanges having
   risky and unstable
3. Join 2 dataframes and obtain exchanges not meeting criteria
4. Update the consecutiveness for current date
5. Merge with original dataset.

I am trying following commands. But, having issues and not able to proceed with 3,4,5

```
case class Telecom(Date: String, Exchange: String, Stability: String, Cosecutive: Int)

val emp1  = sc.textFile("file:/// Filename").map(_.split(",")).map(emp1=>Telecom(emp1(0),emp1(1),emp1(2),emp1(4).trim.toInt)).toDF()

val PreviousWeek = sqlContext.sql("select * from T1 limit 10")

emp1.registerTempTable("T1")

val FailPreviousWeek = sqlContext.sql("Select Exchange, Count  from T1 where Date = '5/05/2017' and Stability in ('RISKY','UNSTABLE')")

val FailCurrentWeek = sqlContext.sql("Select Exchange, Count  from T1 where Date = '6/05/2017' and Stability in ('RISKY','UNSTABLE')")

FailCurrentWeek.join(FailPreviousWeek, FailCurrentWeek("Exchange") === FailPreviousWeek("Exchange"))

val UpdateCurrentWeek = FailCurrentWeek.select($"Exchange",$"Count" +1)

Val UpdateDataSet = emp1.join(UpdateCurrentWeek)

  val UpdateCurrentWeek = FailCurrentWeek.select($"Exchange".alias("Exchangeid"),$"Count" +1)
```

Comment: Why `e` for week `6/05/2017` is `1`?

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfect case for my *beloved* **window aggregate functions**.

I think [lag](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lag(columnName:String,offset:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (with `when`) function could do:

> **lag(columnName: String, offset: Int): Column** returns the value that is offset rows before the current row, and `null` if there is less than offset rows before the current row.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val exchIds = Window.partitionBy("Exchange_Id").orderBy("Date")

val cc = when(lower($"Status") === "risky" && $"lag" === $"Status", 1).
  when(lower($"Status") === "unstable" && $"lag" === $"Status", 1).
  otherwise(0)

val solution = input.
  withColumn("lag", lag("Status", 1) over exchIds).
  withColumn("Consecutiveness", cc).
  orderBy("Date", "Exchange_Id").
  select("Date", "Exchange_Id", "Status", "Consecutiveness")
scala> solution.show
+---------+-----------+--------+---------------+
|     Date|Exchange_Id|  Status|Consecutiveness|
+---------+-----------+--------+---------------+
|5/05/2017|          a|   RISKY|              0|
|5/05/2017|          b|  Stable|              0|
|5/05/2017|          c|  Stable|              0|
|5/05/2017|          d|UNSTABLE|              0|
|5/05/2017|          e| UNKNOWN|              0|
|5/05/2017|          f| UNKNOWN|              0|
|6/05/2017|          a|   RISKY|              1|
|6/05/2017|          b|  Stable|              0|
|6/05/2017|          c|  Stable|              0|
|6/05/2017|          d|UNSTABLE|              1|
|6/05/2017|          e|UNSTABLE|              0|
|6/05/2017|          f| UNKNOWN|              0|
+---------+-----------+--------+---------------+
```

Comment: Hi Jacek. Thanks very much. It is wonder to know this function.

Comment: One question though - If the status for next date (07/05/2017) for a becomes stable then it should again become 0 and then again on 08/05/2017 it becomes risky then it should start from 1 again and not 2. Could you try this with this code and let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used Hive Window partitioning function with multiple loops.

1. First step converting the flags to **boolean**
2. Calculating the Consecutiveness with flag value in one loop
3. Then again having one more window partitioning with considering
   consecutiveness in the loop.

This can be done same as using Spark SQL.